# Sticking side menu to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been looking into sticking a "div" to the top of the screen when you scroll past it, or making the div scroll with the page when it reaches the top of the screen.

The issue i get when i try this matter is that changing to `position: fixed;` using either jquery or the simple css, removes the float from the element.

My layout look somewhat like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ThSXm/33/ ***<--*** updated

So when the float is removed, the `id="content"` get's overlapped by the sidemenu, making the sidemenu bigger and out of place.

I need a solution where you dont have to alter the position of the elements or if there is some fix i can make on the content div so it wont get overlapped when changing the positions.

***Update***

Sandeeproop managed to help me with the positioning, but the scroll matter is still a issue.

As i mentioned in the comment for this question, the div has to scroll/stick to the top of the screen when the div is close to the top or reaches the top (and preferably stop once the div reaches the footer or is close to reaching the footer), because there are more divs (header/slideshow etc) before we reach the side menu, and you wont see the menu if you just use `position: fixed`.

Any thoughts?

***/update***

Looking forward to some answers!

//Jim

Comment: You mean you want the `div` scroll together with your window?

Comment: @jhyap either making it scroll with the window once the div almost reaches the top so if you add more li's it wont get hidden, or making it stick to the top of the screen. Doesn't matter which one. once you enter the page the side menu is a bit down on the page hence the header and a image slideshow, so it has to be determined once the div reaches or is close to reach the top of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you question correctly.
Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ThSXm/22/).

```
#nav {
  width: 136px;
  position: fixed;
  background: #FF0000;
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
#content{
  width: 80%;
  height: 600px;
  background: #FF9966;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 170px;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

Comment: This works, however the issue using this is that it wont be responsive since the margin is in pixels. I use a different one for cellphones and tabs, but even laptops and pc's have different resolutions, do you think it's possible to do it without the `margin-left`, or do you think doing the margin in `em or %` would work for a responsive layout?

Comment: Also, as i mentioned in the comment for the question, it has to be once the side div is close or reaches the top, because there are more divs in the way, and you wont see the menu if you just use ´position: fixed´

Answer (score 0):

You can set fixed margin-top values for nav and content elements.
Something like that http://jsfiddle.net/ThSXm/26/

```
#nav {
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background: #FF0000;
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
#content{
    width: 80%;
    height: 600px;
    background: #FF9966;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
```

Comment: It's not the top div i want to stick, it's the red div as Sande did.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is "position: sticky".
This is not yet supported by many browsers, but here is a pollyfill for it
http://philipwalton.github.io/polyfill/demos/position-sticky/

Comment: it doesn't have to be sticky, i would rather prefer if the sidemenu scroll with the page once the top is close to it. and then stop if it's close to reaching the footer. I believe this can be achieved by using jquery or jscript. I have one patch of code which works on the index, but once i load the next page that is without the slideshow the menu is far down and can't be seen. I'll update the question with the jquery

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a solution where you use position:absolute on the element? 
Have it being absolute untill you need it to stick and then change it to fixed.

Here is a simple fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dXe97/

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > boxTop) {
$box.css({
    'position':'fixed',
    'top': 0
    });
}else{
$box.css({
    'position':'absolute',
     'top': 150
});
};
```

The .box element is absolute positioned, but when you scroll down passed the element, it is changed to fixed and its top value is set to 0, and back again when you scroll up.

Comment: tried it out, but it seems like it doesnt work for me, does it require a fixed height of the element for it to work? I already am using absolute atm. I dont want anything to be fixed on the website to gain responsive design.